# GPS connection is lost and does not recover

Tags: gps, smartphone, windows-mobile-6.5

We have developed an application on Windows.net mobile framework and it is used on a Windows 6.5 Smartphone. for our location based application. Our application is real time and tracks our employees. We are finding that the device loses its GPS signal.

Has anyone managed to restart the GPS receiver so that it starts giving the GPS signal again. I would be ever so gratefull if someone can help. We are using GeoFramework2.0 to deliver the geographic information that you need.

Regards

Sandy

Answer (score 0):

The GPS is "shut down" when no application is using it. Just close your handles and re-open them.

If the GPS on your device is part of the WWAN radio (i.e. cellular phone) it may get put in to a low power state rather than being actually shut off. In that case, you can try [restarting the radio](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103104/Radio-Power).

If that doesn't work, some GPS's will allow you to send proprietary commands to them to force a reset or clear the memory. These commands are not standard and will differ significantly by manufacturer. If you have a SiRF GPS, take a look at the [SiRF Binary Protocol Reference](http://gpsd.googlecode.com/files/SiRF-SiRF-v2_4.pdf).